# Drupal8 site status - "unsupported release" / "not supported" is this deliberate?

Tags: 8, status-messages

Is this a deliberate message as drupal8 is not yet the latest production release?

The reason for raising this question is that it was unexpected in my opinion to see this. I would not have expected to see messages about unsupported / not supported - after all, Drupal 8 is being very actively developed, so to my mind it IS supported. Maybe it depends on the point of view - i.e. for production, then no, not yet. Please advise, thanks!

(see screenshot below)

[image: drupal8 unsupported release messages]

Tried searching issue list for drupal 8 on drupal.org a few times but blank screen - perhaps volume of issues and peak time may be causing the results to not be displayed. Haven't raised this as an issue because it may be something I've not done right in the setup.

Wondering if it might be related to this problem (which appears to be just a warning, though):

`$ drush up
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.`

(Discussed here: [Error when updating modules with Drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/error-when-updating-modules-with-drush) )

My system setup

- Running on a puphpet.com configured VM, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit
- `PHP 5.5.12-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: May 12 2014 13:46:35)`
- `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`
- `Drush Version   :  7.0-dev`

Obtained drupal8 doing the following:

`$ git clone --branch 8.x http://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git drupal8.localvm
Cloning into 'drupal8.localvm'...`

and then

`$ git pull
Already up-to-date.`

Comment: I'm going to hold on answering the question for someone with more Drupal 8 experience than me, but unless you are going to work on patches / debug, you should checkout one of the alpha tags.  They will be a little more stable that what is in HEAD.

Comment: +1 thanks MPD - I think you're onto something here. That does make sense actually, after all, would one download a dev version of a module rather than an alpha, beta or released version and expect the same level of support. *development* is the salient word. I reckon if I went on simplytest.me or trydrupal8.com and spun up a vanilla D8 install there, my findings there would perhaps confirm it is not an issue with my setup and also support what you said. But yes, would be happy for other folks to chime in...

Comment: I quickly spun up a D8-alpha11 site on simplytest.me and it shows the same message. I guess it's just Drupal's way of saying "this is not ready for production sites, use at your own risk, updates may break things, there will be no security advisories for this release, etc. etc". Other than that, I wouldn't worry about it :-)

Comment: To add further supporting thoughts on this, I think the "unsupported" status means that updates aren't available via drush (and therefore without the hook_update / updatedb support for any db schema changes etc.) Instead, code updates are available via git pull - so it is left up to the developer to address any db issues, in fact, a tool has been written to help with that: https://gist.github.com/cam8001/9270022 So yes, it all makes a lot of sense now. Thanks again marcvangend and MPD!

Answer (score 0):

That was probably a warning in Alpha. We're now at Beta 7, and it's now yellow instead of red:[image]
There are currently 55 critical issues remaining:
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?priorities=400&version=8.x
Which still gives a nice trend line toward 0, and release candidates:
https://plot.ly/~xjm/37/remaining-critical-issues-during-the-drupal-8-beta/